# open local terminal in vscode when running in ssh mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I connect via ssh to a remote machine in vscode, the integrated terminal opens a terminal in the remote machine. Is there a way to open a terminal panel with a terminal of my local machine?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using the command palette (default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>), there is an option

`Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal (local)`

Comment: I found that split doesn't work for local terminal. Do you know if there is any work around?

Comment: this is great, is there a way to add it to the terminal menu?

Comment: `Create New Integrated Terminal (local)` only without `Terminal:` worked for me.