# How to open local terminal when running VSCode in a Dev Container?

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-container, vscode-remote

I'm writing code with VSCode from inside a [VSCode container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers).

[I can open terminals inside the dev container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_opening-a-terminal), but I can't figure out how to open a (VSCode integrated) terminal in my local machine.

I can of course open a separate terminal application like iTerm2, but it's far more convenient to use VSCode's integrated terminal panel. Is opening a local terminal possible with VSCode dev containers?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. But could you maybe ssh from the dev container to your local machine?

Comment: @carlfriedrich Yeah that's true. Not as convenient, but should be possible.

Comment: I have posted an answer to make this more convenient.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This solution is provided in the Accepted Answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815283/open-local-terminal-in-vscode-when-running-in-ssh-mode?rq=1), so if the below helps, go and upvote that.

> Using the command palette (default ctrl+shift+p/cmd+shift+p), there is an option
>
> Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal (local)

[image]

Comment: Just tested it, works great. idk how I missed this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you have [key-based SSH access](https://askubuntu.com/a/46935/839504) from the container to the host, you can add a [terminal profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles) to your remote settings (run command `Preferences: Open Remote Settings (JSON) (Dev Container)` to open them):

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash (Host)": {
            "path": "ssh",
            "icon": "terminal-bash",
            "args": [
                "user@host",
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

This will get you an according `bash (Host)` entry in your "Add Terminal" drop-down menu:

[image]

Comment: This answer helped me to open my SSH terminal from Devcontainer. It is really good