# Is there a way to open ssh terminal when we are inside Devcontainer in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-devcontainer

I am connecting to ssh machine in which I have installed Docker.
From the ssh machine I will use Devcontainer.
I am using Devcontainer most of the time. Some time I need to run commands from terminal in ssh. During that time i am doing 'Reopen folder in ssh' and run commands in terminal.

Is there a way that I can open one terminal in SSH and one in Devcontainer at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to open local terminal when running VSCode in a Dev Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145541/how-to-open-local-terminal-when-running-vscode-in-a-dev-container)

The above post has an answer for this situation.

From command pallete -> Preferences: Open Remote Settings (JSON) (Dev Container) in devcontainer .
I need to add this

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash (Host)": {
            "path": "ssh",
            "icon": "home",
            "args": [
                "user@host",
            ],
        },
    },
}
```